# Slim Pen 2 stops working when reinstalling Windows 11

Tags: windows, drivers, microsoft-surface

About 6 months ago I installed the operating system on my Surface Pro 8 from Windows 11 to Windows 11, no change itself. Then when I installed drivers and others the Slim Pen 2 stopped working, so I contacted Microsoft and they changed my keyboard.

The thing is that it worked again until I reinstalled the operating system again from Windows 11 to Windows 11 and it fails me again. The problem is that the Slim Pen 2 does not load on the keyboard, which it does it comes with a loading slot for the Slim Pen 2.

My first hypothesis is that there is a bad driver installed, since nothing appears in the updates nor in the optional updates. I have installed the update package that Microsoft gives you, but nothing still does not work.

Any solution before calling Microsoft and losing my Slim Pen 2 for about 10 days?

Comment: Why did they change your keyboard if your Slim Pen 2 couldn't be detected? Why do you keep reinstalling Windows 11? [Have you installed the Surface Pro 8 drivers?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103503)

Comment: What does it mean "from Windows 11 to Windows 11"?

Comment: @Ramhound I think that the reason why I reinstall windows is irrelevant to the solution of my problem, and if as well I comment "when I installed drivers" i have installed it.
Also, as you said before, the reason is because it stopped working before

Comment: Have you fully updated Windows, including optional updates?

Comment: @Harrymc Well, I went from having a windows 11 to having windows 11 again, I did not install another operating system or a previous version of windows and that my current operating system is a windows 11

Yes, in the question explicitly that nothing appears in the updates, that is: the system is completely updated including the additional ones

Comment: Did you do a In-Place Upgrade of Windows keeping data and apps, or did you reformat the disk and started from scratch?

Comment: @harrymc Total formatting and from 0 although with an image with macrium from the previous installation

Comment: @DavidGonzalo - So you are restoring from an offline image of the device, I assume after you got the pen working again, you updated that image? As for the drivers, since you can’t use Device Manager to install drivers, and Windows Update might not be downloading the correct drivers I wanted to make sure you were installing the recommended drivers. But I can see my question has irritated you so I will be bowing out of trying to troubleshoot your issue. Instead of replying to 3-4 people with different comments just [edit] your question

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know if I haven't explained myself or if you haven't understood me but half of the things are not as you say, I recommend that if you want to help, read the question and the comments again. At what point have I said that I do not have an administrator? or that I am doing an installation from an offline image,... I think we have not understood each other :(

Comment: @DavidGonzalo - You said you restored a macrium image of your system. That image would be offline or online, but you didn’t Reset or perform an in-place upgrade to the same version of Windows 11. Your question makes no mention of macrium at all. I read your question. At this point I cannot help you because, to be honest, you seem insulted with the questions I have raised and the feedback I have provided. Speaking of device manager, care to provide a screenshot of it, and any information on the pen of keyboard, still confused how the keyboard is linked to the pen (but I only have a SP3)

Comment: @Ramhound I repeat, here a colleague has asked me if I did the installation from scratch or restoring files and configuration, my answer from scratch but I have an image with macrium. If you feel insulted, I apologize since it was not my intention. but I also tell him that I think there is no reason to feel insulted...